# Able to ssh but not able to browse centos server

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I recently installed the CentOs server on the VM and I am using a Host Only Interface, and have set the IP address of the host and Centos. I am able to SSH from the terminal of the host to Centos but I am not able to access the test website from my browser.

Can anyone tell me what can be done to access the test website?

Comment: Try to look at `netstat -l -n`, if your web server is listening on port you want. Try to telnet webserver port from your host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Host-Only networking. This completely isolates the virtual machine from the Internet and provides connectivity only to the virtual machine host.

Instead, use bridged or NAT networking.

---

Also, CentOS has a built in firewall and it's turned on by default. You need to disable it or run `system-config-firewall-tui` as root to reconfigure it.

Comment: Thank you Micheal, but I do not need the internet access, I just want to access the test website from the host through the browser using the IP address that I have set to the Guest in the VM.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Sounds like you may have a firewall issue.

Comment: There is no firewall wall tui on my centos, all i can find is the system-config-network-tui. Is there any other way that I can disable the firewall? 
One small doubt, since I am able to ssh, doesn't it meant that the firewall has been disabled?

Comment: You probably need to install it, then: `yum install system-config-firewall-tui`

Comment: Is there any other way that i can disable the firewall?

Comment: Thank you Micheal, my apache was down, set it up and then bought the iptables down. working without any hassle now!